# "Required module not found" for module that exists in node_modules

Tags: flowtype

Some modules just seem to be invisible to Flow. For example I have [react-native-overlay](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-overlay) installed via npm into my node_modules directory but I get a whole bunch of errors like this from Flow:

```
[js/components/DatePickerOverlay.js:18
 18: let Overlay = require('react-native-overlay');
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ react-native-overlay. Required module not found
```

This module doesn't have types so it would be fine if I could just get Flow to ignore it entirely.

Here's my .flowconfig (based on React Native's one):

https://gist.github.com/almost/20c6caf6d18d0e5c689f

As you can see I'm on flow 0.20.1 and I have module.system=haste (as required by React Native)

I tried adding a //$FlowIgnore comment to the import lines but then Flow complains about an unneeded ignore comment! I also tried creating a react-native-flow.js.flow file with a dummy export which seemed to work at first but then after a flow restart stopped working.

Any ideas for how to either help Flow find this module or make it ignore the import line completely?

Comment: I wrote up a GitHub Issue for Flow about fixing this error or improving this error message: [Should not get “Required module not found” error when importing a file ignored within .flowconfig](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/3945)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're ignoring it here: https://gist.github.com/almost/20c6caf6d18d0e5c689f#file-flowconfig-L42-L50

If you don't mind manually typing it up, add a react-native-overlay.js to your interfaces and type up a couple signatures.

Comment: Arg! I totally missed that, I had that as a workaround for a bug in a previous version of Flow then totally forgot about it. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to tell flow that I want to ignore a library in node_modules and also not provide any flow-typed declaration? I want flow to totally ignore that library, whenever I interface with it, flow can consider it valid. I take that risk. Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the library doesn't exist in [flow-typed](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed).

A simple fix could be creating the following entry in the .flowconfig file:

```
[ignore]
<PROJECT_ROOT>/libdefs.js
[libs]
./libdefs.js
```

If using flowtype < 0.60.0 add in `libdefs.js`

```
// @flow

declare module "react-native-overlay" {
    declare var exports: any;
}
```

Or if using flowtype > 0.60.0

```
declare module 'react-native-overlay' {
    declare module.exports: any;
}
```

**Note:** `any` is an unsafe type so you can always take advantage of improve the definition of the library

Hope that helps,